# Twilio - how do I transfer an active outbound call to a queue?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-javascript

I am trying to add the option to transfer an outbound call to a task queue.
I have it working just fine for inbound calls which are originally enqueued, then answered by the workers. But when I try to do the same thing on an outgoing call the call just drops.

This is what I'm using at the moment to place the call back into a queue. (C#)

**Update In progress call**

```
await CallResource.UpdateAsync(
            pathSid: sid,
            url: new Uri($"{_CallbackUrl}/EnqueueTransfer/{department}")
        );
```

**CallBack Response**

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
response.Play(new Uri("**URL**/please_wait_recording.Mp3"));
Enqueue enqueue = new Enqueue(workflowSid: _workflowSid);
enqueue.Task($"{{\"selected_department\":\"{department.ToLower()}\"}}");
response.Append(enqueue);
return new TwiMLResult(response);
```

Any ideas on why this only works for inbound calls and how could I get this working for outbounds?

My outbounds are created using the js client

```
let newCall = await device.connect({
        params: {
            To: formatNumber(number),
            From: worker.attributes?.contact_uri,
            WorkerTeam: worker.attributes?.team,
            WorkerDepartment: worker.attributes?.department
        }
    });
```

***#### UPDATE ####***

The above code is working for both in and outbound calls ***HOWEVER*** when I transfer an already transferred outbound call. The calls drop from the customer phone and the agent gets redirected to the queue. I've tried updating the call resource using the following:

```
        var Call2 = await CallResource.FetchAsync(pathSid: transfer.CallSid);
        ResourceSet<CallResource> calls;
        string sid= transfer.CallSid;

        calls = await CallResource.ReadAsync(parentCallSid: transfer.CallSid);
        if (Call2.Direction.ToLower() == "inbound")
        {                
            sid = calls.FirstOrDefault().Sid;                
        } 

        await CallResource.UpdateAsync(
            pathSid: sid,
            url: new Uri($"{_CallbackUrl}/Transfer/{transfer.Team}")
        );
```

Comment: What happens when you do that? Can you explain the outcome when you run that update? Do you see errors?

Comment: Is the problem now that the customer phone gets dropped? When you are in a 1:1 call, moving one call out of that will send the other call onto the next TwiML it needs to execute and if there is no other TwiML then it will end. Is that something that might help?